# FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession is not displayed without the Facebook App

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my application, I need to use Feed Dialog for the cases when Facebook App is not installed in users phone.
Even though I can share content with FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams method, I can't get Feed Dialog work. Dialog isn't opening and handler is not getting called.

```
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil  parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                } else {
                    if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                        NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                    } else {
                        NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                        if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                            NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                        } else {
                            NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                            // do stuff
                            NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }];
```

Teste on iOS7 and iOS8 and the result it's always the same.

Comment: I had similar problem, it was the params.  If you add your params code I may be able to help you.

Comment: Those are my params: `params.link = shareUrl
                params.name = subj ?? summaryToDisplay
                params.caption = nil
                params.picture = pictureUrl
                params.linkDescription` Where the first 2 are NSURL

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to change both the picture and link fields from type NSURL to NSString.  In the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls#feeddialog) there is a good example of how to do it:

```
   NSMutableDictionary *params =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
 @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
 @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
 @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
 @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
 nil];
```

I believe this would fix your problem.